# Javascript: Ordering a list by the contents of span within li

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

So I have the following list which I want to do the following on:

1. Hide the **li** if that person has 0 posts.
2. Order the list on the number of posts, so highest is first.
3. Then only display the first 4 items in the list.

List code:

```
<div id="et_authors-3" class="widget et_pb_widget widget_et_authors">
    <div class="widget_content">
        <ul class="widget_list">
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Barry White</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">1 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Bob Marley</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">11 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Elton John</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">4 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Stevie Wonder</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">5 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Michael Jackson</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">12 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Elvis Presley</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">0 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
                    <h3 class="title">Phil Collins</h3>
                    <span class="post-meta">0 Posts</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have managed to do point 1 & 3 using the below JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var toremove = []
  var authors = document.getElementById("et_authors-3");
  var ul = authors.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("ul");
  var items = ul[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var author = items[i];
    var author_link = author.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var author_post_meta = author_link[0].getElementsByTagName("span");
    var posts_number = author_post_meta[0].innerHTML.split(" ")[0];
    if (posts_number <= 0) {
        items[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
        ++count;
    }
    if (count > 4) {
        items[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
})();
```

But I can't quite figure out how to do the ordering based on the number of posts. The HTML can't be edited, as I have just pulled that from a WordPress widget for one of my themes, which I don't want to have to look at changing.

The code so far, so you can see 1& 2 in action is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adambirds/ztnm8Lea/)

Comment: How are you getting the data for all of that html? Is it hard coded or coming from a server as json or something?

Comment: That is done from within my WordPress theme, it basically lists all the authors on my site. It's built in to theme, but the theme supports adding java script to manipulate the theme and widgets  to your liking.

Comment: So, to clarify, do you have access to that data apart from digging it out of the html?

Comment: I imagine either the php or the javascript that the widget's built-in grabs the info from the database, well it would do or using some of the wordpress codex, but I'm unsure how I'd access that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might transform the `li`s into an array, so you can concisely manipulate them with array methods like `filter`, `sort`, and `slice`:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('.widget_list');
const liToPostCount = li => Number(li.querySelector('span').textContent.match(/^\d+/));

const lis = [...ul.children];
const highestFour = lis
  .filter((li) => liToPostCount(li) > 0)
  .sort((a, b) => liToPostCount(b) - liToPostCount(a))
  .slice(0, 4);
lis.forEach(li => li.remove());
highestFour.forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
```

```html
<div id="et_authors-3" class="widget et_pb_widget widget_et_authors">
  <div class="widget_content">
    <ul class="widget_list">
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Barry White</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">1 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Bob Marley</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">11 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Elton John</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">4 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Stevie Wonder</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">5 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Michael Jackson</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">12 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Elvis Presley</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">0 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Phil Collins</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">0 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to completely remove the non-passing `li`s, then change their style instead of calling `.remove()`:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('.widget_list');
const liToPostCount = li => Number(li.querySelector('span').textContent.match(/^\d+/));

const lis = [...ul.children];
lis.forEach((li) => li.style.display = 'none');
const highestFour = lis
  .filter((li) => liToPostCount(li) > 0)
  .sort((a, b) => liToPostCount(b) - liToPostCount(a))
  .slice(0, 4);
highestFour.forEach((li) => {
  li.style.display = 'block';
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<div id="et_authors-3" class="widget et_pb_widget widget_et_authors">
  <div class="widget_content">
    <ul class="widget_list">
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Barry White</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">1 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Bob Marley</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">11 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Elton John</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">4 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Stevie Wonder</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">5 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Michael Jackson</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">12 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Elvis Presley</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">0 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://example.com" class="widget_list_author">
          <h3 class="title">Phil Collins</h3>
          <span class="post-meta">0 Posts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked like a charm. Spent hours working that, wish I could put that together in a matter of seconds like that. Only thing I had to do was change how it got the ul as .widget_list is used in the other widgets to. Worked excellently. Remove was ideal, only used styleas couldn't get remove working.